# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: iView

Tags: vue.js, iview

When I open the page, there comes an error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: iView

the snapshot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

in the `main.js` code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import iView from 'iview';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Routers from './router';

import Util from './libs/util';
import App from './app.vue';
import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css';


Vue.use(VueRouter);


Vue.use(iView);   // this is the line 14

...
```

but the `iview` and `iview-loader` is exists in my `node_modules`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the iView import statement to the following:

```
import iView from 'iview/dist/iview.min';
```

Frequently you'll find that distribution packages contain the production version of the library located within a `dist` directory. Seeing as the stylesheet is located there, I'd assume the js is there as well.

```
// likely that the iview js in this directory 
import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css';
```